# Difference in a C++ pointer behavior when incremented in the for loop definition vs inside for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, pointers

I'm onto a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-cycle-ii/) (Floyd’s Cycle Detection Algorithm for Linked List) wherein I noticed a strange behavior on the pointer states.
When I change the pointer state inside the for loop, the program executes correctly (pointer states move to the right states):

```
ListNode *detectCycle(ListNode *head) {
        
        if(!head or !head->next)
            return nullptr;
        
        ListNode *slow, *fast;
        
        for(slow = head, fast = head; fast && fast->next;)
        {
            slow = slow->next, fast = fast->next->next; // This hops the pointers correctly

            if(slow == fast)
            {
                slow = head;
                while(slow != fast)
                {
                    slow = slow->next;
                    fast = fast->next;
                }
                return slow;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
```

But when I state change `slow` & `fast` in the for loop definition, the state change is wrong and the program doesnt give the right output.

```
ListNode *detectCycle(ListNode *head) {
        
        if(!head or !head->next)
            return nullptr;
        
        ListNode* slow, *fast;
        
        for(slow = head, fast = head; fast && fast->next; slow = slow->next, fast=fast->next->next) // Pointers dont hop correctly
        {
            if(slow == fast)
            {
                slow = head;
                while(slow != fast)
                {
                    slow = slow->next;
                    fast = fast->next;
                }
                return slow;
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }
```

I dont know whats causing this. In my head, incrementing the pointers in the for loop definition vs immediately in the for loop should be the same thing. Can someone throw an insight as to why incrementing pointers within the loop vs in the for loop signature leads to different behavior?

Comment: Have a look here: https://godbolt.org/z/PTYeTn1s8

Comment: Putting `slow = slow->next, fast=fast->next->next` in the _iteration-expression_ in the `for` loop is the same as putting as the last line in the loop body - so it's not the same as putting it first in the loop body.

Comment: Your first sample always "hops" `fast` and `slow` BEFORE executing the `if (slow == fast)` statement.   The second "hops" AFTER executing the `if (slow == fast)` statement.   Since the body of the `if (slow == fast)` statement changes `slow` and `fast`, this causes your code samples to behave differently.

Comment: Use parentheses for clarity!  Did you mean `(slow = slow->next), (fast = fast->next->next);` or `slow = (slow->next, fast = fast->next->next);`?  In fact, inside the loop body you would be well advised to use two separate statements, not the comma-operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A

```cpp
for (init-statement; condition; iteration-expression)
{
    dostuff();
}
```

maps to

```cpp
{
    init-statement
    while ( condition ) 
    {
        dostuff();
        iteration-expression ;
    }
}
```

so we get

```cpp
{
    slow = head, fast = head;
    while (fast && fast->next)
    {
        slow = slow->next, fast = fast->next->next; 
        dostuff(); // for example purposes only. Not really replacible with a function 
    }
}
```

and

```cpp
{
    slow = head, fast = head;
    while (fast && fast->next)
    {
        dostuff();
        slow = slow->next, fast=fast->next->next;
     }
}
```

In the first, `slow` and `fast` are always updated before `dostuff()`.

In the second, `dostuff` happens before `slow` and `fast` are updated, so the values of `slow` and `fast` used in `dostuff` will be different on the first loop iteration.